# Export list CRUD with MPDF + OB_start()

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

Good morning guys, developing a CRM using the CodeIgniter framework and I'm not managing to export some CRUD lists using an MPDF library.

I'm trying to use an ob_start () function as indicated in the library's own manual, but when exporting, I get the following
formatting error as a return:

[error formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqm53.png)

When in fact a pdf spreadsheet would return

Below, the codes used:

view:

```
<li><a href='gerarPdfRelatorio' title="Exportar"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a></li>
 <div class="conteudo tabelaMovCaixa">
    <div class="col-xs-12 usuarioTitulo">
        <div class="input entrada1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAll" onclick="selecionaTodosCheckbox()" value="Selecione">
        </div>
        <div class="conta">
            Conta
        </div>
        <div class="descricao">
            Descrição
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            Vencimento
        </div>
        <div class="tipo">
            Tipo
        </div>
        <div class="valor">
            Valor
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </form>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url('configuracoes/excContasCheckbox') ?>" method="POST">
        <?php if ($dados_caixa_filtro == null) { ?>
            <?php
            $data = date('d/m/Y');
            $data2 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-1 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));
            $data3 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));
            ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 vencimento">
                <h5>Vencimento: <?php echo $data ?></h5>
            </div>
            <?php
            if (!empty($dados_caixa)) {
                foreach ($dados_caixa as $dados) {
                    $checkbox = [];
                    $checkbox[] = $dados->id_contas_pagar_receber;
                    foreach ($checkbox as $checkbox => $value) {
                        //echo "ID da conta : ".$value."<br />";
                    }
                    if (date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dados->vencimento)) == $data) {
                        $urlExcluir = base_url('configuracoes/excContaPR') . "/" . $dados->id_contas_pagar_receber;
                        if ($dados->tipo_pessoa == '1') {
                            echo "<div class='col-xs-12 usuario saida'>";
                        } else if ($dados->tipo_pessoa == '2') {
                            echo "<div class='col-xs-12 usuario entrada'>";
                        }
                        echo "<div class='input entrada1'>"

                            . "<input type='checkbox' name='emp_id[]' value='$value' id='emp_id' onclick=verificarCheckBox() >"


                            . "</div>"
                            . "<div class='conta'>"
                            . "$dados->nome"
                            . "</div>"
                            . "<div class='descricao'>"
                            . $dados->descricao
                            . "</div>"
                            . "<div class='data'>";
                        if ($dados->vencimento == '') {
                            echo "----------";
                        } else {
                            echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dados->vencimento));
                        }
                        echo "</div>"
                            . "<div class='tipo'>"
                            . $dados->forma_pagamento
                            . "</div>"
                            . "<div class='valor'>"
                            . "<span class='entrada2'>" . 'R$ ' . number_format($dados->valor, 2, ',', '.') . "</span>"
                            . "</div>"
                            . "<div class='actions2'>"
                            . "<li><a onclick='pagar2($dados->id_contas_pagar_receber, $dados->tipo_pessoa)' title='Editar'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a></li>"
                            . "<li><a onclick='pagar($dados->id_contas_pagar_receber, $dados->tipo_pessoa)' title='Pagar'><i class='fas fa-file-invoice-dollar'></i></a></li>"
                            . "<li><a href='#' onclick = \"confirmExclusaoContaPR(" . '\'0' . $dados->id_contas_pagar_receber . '\',' . '\'' . $urlExcluir . '\'' . ");\" title='Excluir'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>"
                            . "</div>"
                            . "</div>";

                        for ($i = 0; $i < count(['checkbox']); $i++) {
                            $id = $value;
                            //echo $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

I am placing the ob_start () function right at the beginning of the view containing the HTML of the page.

Controler:

```
function gerarPdfRelatorio()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('logado') == true) {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Fortaleza');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        
        $dadosC['dados_caixa'] = $this->financeiro->retornaListaMovimentacaoCaixa();
  
        $dadosC['dados_caixa_filtro'] = null;
        if ($this->session->userdata('tipo_filtro_movcaixa')) {
            $this->session->unset_userdata("tipo_filtro_movcaixa");
        }

        $this->load->view('admin/head');
        $dadosC['lista_cliente'] = $this->relatorio->buscaClienteFornecedor();
        $dadosC['lista_centro_custo'] = $this->financeiro->listaCentroCusto();
        $this->load->view('admin/head');
        $this->load->view('admin/relatorio', $dadosC);
    } else {
        $dados['mensagem'] = null;
        $dados['mensagem_tipo'] = 'error';
        $this->paginas($dados);
    }
}
```

This is where I generate the PDF:

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(0);



include_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->debug = true;

$conteudoPDF = $this->load->view('admin/relatorios/relatorio_geral.php', '', true);

$header = '<div><img src="assets/img/logo_contrato2.jpeg" width="800"></div>';

$conteudoPDF = mb_convert_encoding($conteudoPDF, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($conteudoPDF);

ob_clean();


$mpdf->WriteHTML($conteudoPDF, 0);
ob_clean();  


$mpdf->Output();
```

This is the list I'm trying to generate

[tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s0pu.png)

I would like to know how I can format this data to appear in spreadsheet format in pdf

Comment: could you please edit the error message into your Question (as text, not as expired image)

Comment: Edited, thanks for checking @Vickel